# Convertendo Int para String!

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando recuperar algumas informações gravada no banco de dados, só que quando é feito acontece um erro, pois estou tentando pegar um valor "inteiro" e passar para "String", aí não estou conseguindo fazer essa conversão, seguem abaixo os códigos:

```
public class ProdutoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Produto> {

private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<Produto> elementos;

public ProdutoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Produto> elementos) {
    super(context, R.layout.linha_produtos, elementos);
    this.context = context;
    this.elementos = elementos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_produtos, parent, false);
    TextView id = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
    TextView descricao = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
    TextView preco = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtVVenda);
    TextView estoque = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtEstoque);
    id.setText(Integer.parseInt(elementos.get(position).getId()));
    descricao.setText(elementos.get(position).getDescricao());
    preco.setText(elementos.get(position).getValorVenda());
    estoque.setText(elementos.get(position).getEstoqueAtual());
    return rowView;
}
```

O erro acontece aqui `id.setText(Integer.parseInt(elementos.get(position).getId()));`

Aqui está o código do erro:

```
  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:338)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5494)
    at com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1.ProdutoAdapter.getView(ProdutoAdapter.java:32)
```

Obs.: O objeto "ID" é declarado como "INT" na classe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O método [`parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) da classe `Integer` recebe uma `String` e a converte em um valor primitivo do tipo `int`. Como você mesmo disse que `id` é declarado como um `int` na classe `Produto`, a chamada `Integer.parseInt(elementos.get(position).getId())` não faz muito sentido, já que 1) você está passando um `int` para um método que espera `String` como parâmetro e 2) você estaria tentando converter um `int` em um `int`.

Para você converter um valor do tipo `int` em `String`, você precisa do método [`valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)), que, entre outros tipos, pode receber um `int` e convertê-lo em `String`:

```
id.setText(String.valueOf(elementos.get(position).getId()));
```

Então, para resumir, quando você quiser fazer a conversão entre tipos, a classe que você deverá usar é aquela para a qual você quer que seu valor seja convertido, ou seja: se você quer seu valor convertido para `String`, você vai usar métodos de conversão da classe `String`; se você quer seu valor convertido para `double`, vai usar métodos da classe `Double` etc.

Comment: Deu certo, agradeço a atenção!

Comment: Se essa resposta atendeu sua dúvida, clique no símbolo de tick para marcá-la como correta e ajudar os demais usuários.

Comment: Qual simbolo seria esse, para que eu possa clicar???

Comment: No lado superior esquerdo ao lado da resposta, em cinza, um símbolo no formato de "certo" que, ao ser clicado, fica em verde. Aceitar uma resposta como correta ajuda outros usuários que tenham sua dúvida a terem confiança de que aquela resposta resolveu seu problema e poderá resolver o deles também.

Comment: Entendi e feito, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas maneiras de resolver esse problema:

1 - Você pode usar o `String.valueOf`:

`id.setText(String.valueOf(elementos.get(position).getId()));`

2 - Você pode usar concatenação:

`id.setText("" + Integer.parseInt(elementos.get(position).getId()));`

É obvio que a primeira opção é a mais correta a se utilizar, mas nada te impede de usar a segunda.

Comment: Deu certo obrigado.